# Use of increment operator gives build error "swift Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int'"

Tags: swift, unary-operator

In the section [Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html), the Swift Programming Language guide states that ++ is a valid operator:

> “More complex examples include the logical AND operator && (as in if
>   enteredDoorCode && passedRetinaScan) and the **increment operator ++i**,
>   **which is a shortcut to increase the value of i by 1**.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l

However, when attempting this in a playground;

```
import UIKit

let i = 0
i++
```

A build error shows:

**swift Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int'**

Why?

Comment: thanks for the answers. Hopefully this will save others from a few minutes of head scratching and disbelief!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, not the best-worded compiler error.

The problem is that you have declared `i` using `let`.  Since integers are value types, this means `i` is immutable – it cannot be changed once assigned a value.

If you declare `i` as `var i = 0` the code compiles.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `i` as immutable with `let`. Try `var i = 0` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you are changing the value of the variable of a value type (structures or enumerations) inside one of it's methods, you have to define that method as mutating:

```
mutating func modify() {
   ++i
}
```